# Can a Holy Healer's Staff also be Accurate?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, implements

I am currently playing a Cleric (Templar).  I multiclassed to Sentinel Initiate [Druid] which gives me proficiency with staff implements, and I took Superior Implement Training (accurate staff).  Builder only applies the accurate keyword to implements; should it also be able to be applied to magical staves?

Basically, what I want is a +2 Accurate Holy Healer's Staff.  When I add both a +2 Holy Healer's Staff and a +2 Accurate Defensive Staff to my character on builder, the power break down is the same except for an extra +1 to attack for Superior Implement - Accurate staff for the Defensive Accurate Staff.  Should the +2 Accurate Holy Healer's Staff exist, and for either answer, why?

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**

Mostly, anyway. The main issue is interpretation of PHB1 pg221:

> **Arcane Implement:** ... A staff implement can also function as a quarterstaff.

Obviously, if you have an accurate staff, you can use it as a quarterstaff. If you have a quarterstaff, can it be an accurate staff? Nearly every group will tell you that this passage means quarterstaves and staff implements are the *same thing*, in which case an Accurate Holy Healer's Staff should definitely add its +1 bonus (on implement attacks).

The problem is that the Character Builder gets confused when you drop a weapon enchantment (Holy Healer) on a superior implement (accurate staff). You can *do* it, because the devs pretty clearly intended it to work, but in the Builder's mind weapons and implements are Not the Same Thing.

TLDR: Builder is wrong unless your group is a bunch of hardcore rules lawyers; Holy Healer Accurate Staff *does* grant its +1 accuracy bonus on (implement) attacks.

Answer (score 5):

I've investigated the issue and have found the problem.

Holy Healer is a *weapon* enchantment, not an *implement* one. This means the Character builder does not support it's use as an "accurate" implement. Obviously because you are proficient in it as an implement it's enhancement bonuses are added in. As far as I'm concerned there should be no issue adding the Accurate keyword after the fact (and adding the +1 to hit bonus manually to your sheet), as this should be possible (after all, you should be able to add this enchantment to an "accurate" quarterstaff). The price would not change any (prices are set by the enchantment), but this use is not supported natively in the character builder.